# Error: /usr/local must be writable! (update homebrew)

Tags: terminal, homebrew

I ran: `brew update` in terminal (Mac OS)
output: `Error: /usr/local must be writable!`

Anyway, as you can probably tell I am new to working with this. I searched this expecting it to be a common question but only saw not so helpful answers on github. Any help would be appreciated. *Note my terminal did recently switch to zsh with the last update (not too sure what that is).

Comment: Usually this is fixed with `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`  or  `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`!

Comment: @ I copied and pasted the command to install homebrew from their website and it just redownloaded like it wasn't already installed. Now, everything is working. Thanks though @klanomath

Comment: If that solved your issue, post it as an answer and select it as the solution!  It's important to close the loop and definitely not leave things pending in comments!

Comment: Glad your issue was fixed. In the future, please include all brew output and also the output of “brew doctor”.

Answer (score 3):

Wound up just reinstalling homebrew with `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` found at https://brew.sh/ . This cleared everything up and I can download packages. Still not sure why `brew update` didn't do the trick.

Comment: The correct answer. Do not try to change the /usr/local access rights.

Comment: The requested URL returned error: 404